# is_dynamic_sidebar always returns true while using Jetpack visibility

Tags: functions, theme-development, sidebar

If I have any widgets in the sidebar, even if the jetpack visibility is set to not show on that page, is_dynamic_sidebar return true.

Here's the code in my theme functions file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'iartz_add_sidebar_class' );

function iartz_add_sidebar_class() {
    add_filter('body_class','check_has_sidebar');
    function check_has_sidebar($classes) {
        if ( is_dynamic_sidebar() ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'no-sidebar';
        }
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

(I tried using several different hooks thinking that the sidebar would have to unregister or something, but it doesn't seem to matter)

Is there a different way to check for sidebars that would take jetpack visibility into account, or another plugin that would have the same functionality, but also work with is_dynamic_sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `is_active_sidebar('your_sidebar_name or id')` instead of `is_dynamic_sidebar()` to check whether required sidebar has widgets or not.It works for you in this case.